# how does --options-file differ from --connection-param-file

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Sqoop documentation shows example for `--options-file` as:

```
#
# Options file for Sqoop import
#

# Specifies the tool being invoked 
import

# Connect parameter and value
--connect
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db

# Username parameter and value
--username
foo
#
# Remaining options should be specified in the command line.
#
```

As per above if it is only the connection information and as per the comment all remaining options should be specified in the command line, why is it in `--options-file` and not `--connection-param-file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment *Remaining options should be specified in the command line* is misleading. It is there only to show it is possible to have comments in the options file. However, it does **not** mean you cannot specify more options.

I am using options file for Sqoop and they contain connection details as well as `--num-mappers` or `--fields-terminated-by`.